# Converting a Scheme function to Emacs Lisp

Tags: scheme

I am taking efforts to rephrase an example from [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html)

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define (average-damp f)
  (lambda (x) (average x (f x))))
(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))
(define (square x)
  (* x x))
((average-damp square) 10)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 55
```

After spent hours on it and got

```
(defun average-damp (f)
  (lambda (x) (average x (funcall f x))))

(defun average (x y)
  ;; Keep the float
  (/ (+ x y) 2.0))

(defun square (x)
  (* x x))

(funcall #'(average-damp 'square) 10)
```

Still report error `invalid function`, yet I am lost

Could you please provide any hints?

Comment: To learn about Emacs Lisp, do `M-: (info "(eintr) Top")`, or do `C-h i` followed by choosing `Emacs Lisp Intro`. See also [Learn Emacs Lisp](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LearnEmacsLisp) on EmacsWiki. You will spend less time that way, I predict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. There are only two little details you need to take care of:

1. Remove the quoting `#'` in `(funcall #'(average-damp 'square) 10)`. You **do want to eval** `average-damp` and give you the actual function for the `funcall`. That is what Aquaactress correctly statet as [**problem 1**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53507/2370).
2. For the form

   ```el
      (defun average-damp (f)
        (lambda (x) (average x (funcall f x))))
   ```

   to work you need [lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html). The argument list of `average-damp` goes into its lexical environment. You can refer to that variable in the `lambda` that is within the lexical environment of `average-damp`. So your source block defining `average-damp` should have the `:lexical t` header argument. It should look like follows:

   ```el
   #+begin_src emacs-lisp :lexical t
      (defun average-damp (f)
        (lambda (x) (average x (funcall f x))))
   #+end_src
   ```

Comment: ty, why both ` #'square` and `'square` works in (funcall (average-damp #'square) 10) ?

Comment: @Algebra That is one of the specialities of Elisp. Elisp does not have a special obarray for function symbols. Instead each symbol has a function cell beside the other stuff like the value cell and the plist. Thus, `#'` just stands for the ordinary quote. Nevertheless it is recommended to use `#'` since Elisp checkers can warn if the quoted symbol does not have a function definition.

Comment: Could I consult that is it a good practice that while on  one hand exploiting SICP, on the other hand learning Elisp by replace scheme with elisp? I doubt that scheme might be very fluent and powerful in prototype thinking without interrupting by the detailed implementations.

Comment: I assume [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/converting-a-scheme-function-to-emacs-lisp/53509?noredirect=1#comment83528_53505) has already answered the question [in your comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53505/converting-a-scheme-function-to-emacs-lisp/53509?noredirect=1#comment83534_53509). Certainly you can use [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) to learn the principles but I would use Scheme to try the programs. Maybe, translating Scheme to Elisp is a good one-time excersize but not for the examples of a whole book.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems I found with the code you wrote.

#### problem 1

```
(funcall #'(average-damp 'square) 10)
```

`funcall` requires a function as it's first argument. However, here you're trying to pass in the unevaluated list
`(average-damp 'square)` as if it were a function. But it's not, it's data.

Remember that `#'` is a shorthand for `function` and `function` does not evaluate it's arguments (see [anonymous functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions)). So it does not evaluate `(average-damp 'square)`.

#### problem 2

The other problem is your definition of `average-damp`.

```
(defun average-damp (f x)
  (lambda (x) (average x (funcall f x))))
```

`lambda` does not evaluate it's body. Therefore the `f` that you're passing into `average-damp` won't end up replacing the `f` in `(funcall f x)` which it seems like is what you want.

As an illustration, this is what your version of `average-damp` returns when passed in with `square`.

```
(average-damp 'square) ;=> (lambda (x) (average x (funcall f x)))
```

Note that the `f` still hasn't been replaced with `square`.

Consequently, when the lambda this function is called, it won't know what `f` is (unless you defined a global variable `f`) and you're bound to get a `Symbol's value as variable is void: f` error.

#### solution

To address problem 2 you can use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) to ensure that the value of `average-damp`'s parameter, `f`, is replaced with `square`.

And to address problem 1, you should remove the `#'`. You don't need it because you want `(average-damp 'square)` to be evaluated so that it returns a function, which is what `funcall` requires as it's first argument.

```
(defun average-damp (f)
  `(lambda (x) (average x (funcall #',f x))))

(funcall (average-damp 'square) 10) ;=> 55.0
```

Comment: Note that the backquoting in your solution to problem 2 is old-style. Nowadays one uses lexical binding. See [my answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53509/2370). Motivation: If the question originates from an effort to transform a Scheme library into an Emacs library the coding style guidelines for Emacs libraries require `lexical-binding` anyway. So `average-damp` is already a closure in such a library.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not enter `x` value to `(average-damp )` in your code.

You should declare `x` as a function argument or define `(average-damp )` as a macro.

```
(defun average-damp (f x)
  (average x (funcall f x)))

(defmacro average-damp2 (f)
  `(lambda (x) (average x (funcall ,f x))))

(defun average (x y)
  ;; Keep the float
  (/ (+ x y) 2.0))

(defun square (x)
  (* x x))

;; using function
(funcall #'average-damp #'square 10);; => 55.0
(average-damp #'square 10);; => 55.0

;; using macro
((lambda (x) (average x (square x))) 10);; => 55.0
(funcall (average-damp2 #'square) 10);; => 55.0
```